Power series and radius of convergence of $f(e^{it}) = t(2 \pi - t)$
Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on an open set $U$ containing the closed unit disk centered at the origin and is such that on the unit circle we have $f(e^{it}) = t(2 \pi - t)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$
I am attempting to (a) determine the unique power series which describes $f(z)$ then (b) show that the radius of convergence of the power series is no more than one. Then (c) noting this contradicts the supposed holomorphicity of $f(z)$, explain why this might have been expected.
For (a) plotting around 30 terms of the Taylor series (when $z_0 = 0$) gives a good approximation of $f(z)$ so I have:
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(t - z_0)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(z_0).
\end{align*}
For (b) I have that by the ratio test the radius of convergence is:
\begin{align*}
\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{\left| \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right| }{\left| \frac{1}{n!}\right| } = 0
\end{align*}
I don't what (c) is asking which leads me to think I've missed something in part (b) or (a).
So:
Are (a) and (b) correct?
What contradicts the supposed holomorphicity of $f(z)$ here and why might this have been expected?
Please explain why the phrase "no more than one" is used here, I have an explicit radius of convergence of $0$...

Have you solved $z = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$ to replace $t$ in $t(2\pi - t)$ to actually have a recipe for $f(z)$ in your hand, to repeatedly differentiate to get the series you need?

Yes I have $f(g(t))$ where $g(t):=e^{it}$ so as the unit circle is traversed f takes on the values f(g(t)) = t(2\pi - t).

The values of $f$ inside the disk are determined by the vaues on the boundary and Poisson Integral Formula explcitly defines the values inside. Ref: Rudin's RCA. This is what 'no more than one' means.

$c$ is asking to show that actually there is no such function which is obvious from the fact the boundary value function $t(2\pi-t)$ is not holomorphic on a neighborhood of the unit circle - it is a bit subtler result to show that there is no holomorphic function inside the unit disc with boundary values $t(2\pi-t)$ which is also true

Cauchy's formula gives $$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$ which implies $$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(e^{it})}{(e^{it})^{n+1}}ie^{it}dt$$$$=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}t(2\pi-t)e^{-int}dt=-\frac{2}{n^2}$$ if $n>0$, and $$a_n=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}t(2\pi-t)dt=\frac{2\pi^2}3$$ when $n=0$. We thus get $$f(z)=\frac{2\pi^2}3-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2z^n}{n^2}.$$ Note that the radius of convergence here is $1$, not $0$, but we still get a contradiction because $f$ was assumed to be holomorphic on a set containing the closed disk. If we want another approach it suffices to calculate $$f(1)=\frac{2\pi^2}3-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2}=\frac{2\pi^2}3-\frac{\pi^2}3=\frac{\pi^2}3.$$ However we expect that $f(1)=f(e^{i0})=0(2\pi-0)=0.$
